# ReactJs simple project js file size is huge

Tags: reactjs, gulp, filesize

Please view my code here https://github.com/steelx/ReactBasic

Once you run `gulp`
and go to `./public/` folder, you can see `main.js` its file size is 1.8MB

I need to understand, why its so huge.

Comment: A minified bare-bones react project using uglify would be roughly ~200kb. Is this size minified?

Comment: That size sounds right for an unminified React project, it gets much smaller once you minify. I have a 3MB unminified project here that is 300kb minified, and less than 100kb gzipped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get a trimmed-down production build, you will need to:

1. Set `debug` to `false` in your browserify config - you currently have it set to `true`, so it's generating a sourcemap which accounts for most of the size.
2. Use [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) to replace references to `process.env.NODE_ENV` in the React source with `'production'`.
3. Use [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to minify your code. Step 2 is required to allow the dead code elimination uglify performs to remove chunks of development-only code from the React codebase.

---

Example of expected bundle size using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) to perform the steps above:

```
$ npm run build

> @ build /tmp/ReactBasic-master
> webpack

Hash: 8b3519309382e66318ad
Version: webpack 1.12.2
Time: 6486ms
      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    main.js   133 kB       0  [emitted]  main
main.js.map  1.54 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 157 hidden modules

$ gzip-size public/main.js
38376
```

`webpack.config.js` used for this example:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './jsx/app.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/}
    ]
  }
}
```

`package.json` used for this example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "0.14.1",
    "react-dom": "0.14.1",

    "babel-core": "5.8.33",
    "babel-loader": "5.3.3",
    "webpack": "1.12.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The `main.js` file contains React, React.DOM, your application code and all other dependencies required by React or your code and also some code to make all those modules load and work.

If you have doubts about the filesize, open `main.js` and inspect it.

In my personal experience, 1.8MB for a React project is... normal.

When you put this in production, you will of course minify and zip the javascript.

Comment: if i use webpack to compile the jsx to js then do i need React and React.DOM related files?